# Test the randomness of a black box that outputs random 64-bit floats

Tags: algorithm, random

I got this interview question and need to write a function for it. I failed.

Because it is a phone interview question, I don't think what I am supposed to code really need to be perfect random tester.

Any ideas?

How to write some code to be a reasonable randomness tester within like 30 minutes during an interview?

**edit**

The distribution in this question is *uniformly distributed*

Comment: That looks very hand-wavy to me. For example, a good PRNG is totally deterministic (and thus arguably totally non-random) but if you don't know the seed, it is indistinguishable from a completely random generator

Comment: Did you have an answer or did you fail to give an answer?

Comment: @Bananamansam I didn't/don't have an answer at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this is an interview question, I think the interviewers are looking to assess in two ways:

1. Ability to understand what the requirements of the problem really are.
2. Ability to think of some code that would address those requirements.

This could be a really good interview question in certain settings, especially if the interviewer were willing to prompt the candidate with questions as and when necessary.

In terms of understanding the requirements of the question, it helps if you know that this is a really difficult problem, witness the [Diehard tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) mentioned in [pjs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22917301/834521). Fundamentally I think a candidate would need to demonstrate appreciation of two things:

*(a)* The overall *distribution* of the numbers should match the desired distribution (I'm assuming it is uniform in this case, but as @pjs points out in comments this assumption should be made explicit).

*(b)* Each number drawn should be *independent* from the previous numbers drawn.

With half an hour to code something up in a phone interview, you can't go very far. If I were answering this question I would try to suggest something like:

*(a)* To test the distribution, come up with a set of equal-sized bins for the floating point numbers, and count the numbers that fall into each bin. Plot a histogram and eyeball it (plotting the data is always a good idea). To extend this, you could use a chi-squared test, as described in [amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22916643/834521).

However, as discussed in the comments, and [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~kapadia/project2/node14.html)

> The main problem with chi squared test is the choice of number and size of the intervals. Although rules of thumb can help produce good results, there is no panacea for all kinds of applications.

To this end, the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test can be used. The idea behind this test is that if you a plot of the *ordered* data should be a good fit against the perfect ordered data (known as the cumulative distribution). For a uniform distribution the perfect ordered data is a straight line: you expect the 10th percentile of the data to be 10% of the way through the range, the 20th to be 20% of the way through the range and so on. So, programmatically, you could sort the data, plot it against the ideal value and you should get a straight line. There is also a formal, quantitative statistical test you can apply, which is based on the differences between the actual and ideal values.

*(b)* To test independence, there are multiple approaches. [Autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) at various time lags is one fairly obvious one: to what extent is the value at time *t* similar to the value at time *t+1*, for example. The [runs test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) is another nice one: you convert all the numbers into 1 or 0 depending on whether they fall above or below the median, and then the distribution of the length of runs can be used to construct a statistical test. The runs test can also be used to test for runs in one direction or another, as described [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~kapadia/project2/node17.html) and [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~kapadia/project2/node17.html) (this might be more useful in your case). Both of these have fairly straightforward implementations so long as you have the formulas to hand!

Apart from the diehard tests, other good sources discussing random number generators include [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~kapadia/project2/node12.html) and [here](http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~xmeng/Course/CS6337/Note/master/node42.html).

Comment: Good answer, except the OP never specified uniformity.  That's why I think many of the answers here are off-target.

Comment: @pjs that's a good point. My answer does depend on uniformity and that's a reasonable assumption without any further information, but that assumption ought to checked!

Comment: @pjs PS are you aware of stats.stackexchange.com? Surprised I haven't seen you there having looked at your profile.

Comment: I'm aware of it, but I find the computation side of things fun and intriguing.  I guess you could say stackoverflow has become somewhat of a hobby, where stats.stackexchange.com would be more like a continuation of work.

Comment: Can I use the 64 bits as 64 equal-sized bins?

Comment: @JacksonTale I would just stick to viewing the numbers as double precision and carve up the space equally from whatever the minimum double precision number is to the maximum (assuming, again, a uniformly distribution)

Comment: The problem is how to divide for the equal spaces? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92984/test-the-randomness-uniformly-distributed-on-a-64-bit-float-random-generator

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow the question on stats: I have an account there too. I'm the opposite to @pjs in that respect: I'm a professional programmer and maths/stats is my secondary interest (which I keep hoping I can use professionally:)    In view of the fact you've asked the question over there, I'll just clarify and say that the idea of binning is something sensible to say to an interview question: if you're approaching this professionally you'll look at the diehard tests and similar.

Comment: @TooTone I am just seeking for a easier way and want to know whether that way is correct or not. Also, if for that big range, what if the interviewer asks me how many equal spaces do I need? by the way, I am not good at stats and throwed them all back to university

Comment: @JacksonTale The more data you have, the more bins you can use, but I wouldn't go beyond a few hundred.

Comment: @TooTone becasue teh question is about 64 bit float, so the possible data covers the huge range. I know for example, if I split the range to 100, it won't be bad and e is 1/100. But I want to know whether I use 64 bins and considers about bits instead of whole value is a correct way or not

Comment: @JacksonTale I've expanded my answer; you were right to push me on it as my answer was too weak on part (a) testing the distribution. My initial approach was much more along the lines of trying to say something sensible off-the-cuff for an answer to an interview question. What you're looking for now is heading more into the territory of a well-researched approach to test for randomness. Nevertheless once I thought about it some more, the K-S test is straightforward for uniform data because it's essentially sorting and looking at deviation from a straight-line fit!

Comment: @JacksonTale Regarding binning - you usually decide what your sample size is going to be ahead of time, and then a fairly standard recommendation is us O(sort(n)) bins. The theory is that as n -> infinity the number of bins also -> infinity, but in such a way that so does the expected number of samples per bin.

Answer (score 3):

The way to check if a random number generator (or any other probability for that matter) is matching a desired model (in your case, uniform distribution) - you should use a statistical test, the [Pearson's chi squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).

The test is based on collecting observations, and matching them to the expected probability in according to the theoretic model you are assuming the numbers come from.

At the end, the test gives you the probability that the collected sample indeed came from the given model.

**A simple example:**

Given a cube, and the draws: `[5,3,5,5,1,1]` Is the cube balanced? (`p=1/6` for each of {1,...,6})

Given the above observations we create the Expected vector: `E = [1,1,1,1,1,1]` (each entry is `N/6` - 6 because this is the number of outcomes and `N` is the number of draws, 6 in the above example). And the Observed vector: `O=[2,0,1,0,3,0]`

From this we compute the statistic:

```
Xi^2 = sum((O_i - E_i)^2 / E_i) = 1/1 + 1/1 + 0/1 + 1/1 + 4/1 + 1/1 = 8
```

Now, we need to check what is the probability for `P(Xi^2>=8)`, according to the [chi^2 distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) (one degree of freedom). This probability is ~0.005 (a bit less..). So we can reject the hypothesis that the sample comes from unbiased cube with pretty high probability.

Comment: Is it something that can be coded within 30 minutes in a phone interview?

Comment: @JacksonTale 30 minutes is a lot of time ;) Given that you know the algorithm and are a skilled coder, it's probably possible. It's probably not what they expected though

Comment: can you please give me an example demonstrating `Pearson's chi squared test`? or how to deal with the 64 bit float random number tests?

Comment: @NiklasB. I rarely coded for statistics problems, that's bad

Comment: @JacksonTale I added a simple example for usage of the test on a cube to check if it's unbiased.

Comment: The chi-square test will check for uniformity, but doesn't tell you anything about how random the outcomes are.

Comment: I was typing this at the same time as @pps, whose comment I agree with. I think saying this is "the way" is too strong. For example the chi-squared test doesn't deal very well with `[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5]`. Yes, chi-squared is a good idea, but it's insufficient.

Comment: You have a point. In here I assumed a multi-set (though I mistakenly wrote a vector) - as this is the assumption the pearson's chi^2 works on.

Comment: Even if it passes visual inspection and statistical tests and everything, it still doesn't tell you anything about randomness (as in, unpredictability) of the source... That's just my interpretation of the question though and I think something like this answer is what the interviewers expected

Comment: For example, if the generator produces the same sequence of values everytime you run your program, I wouldn't call it random at all

Comment: Should I convert the float to a 64 bit array, and consider in terms of the 64 slots? i.e., each slot is either 0 or 1, after N sampling, for each slot, the number of times of being 1 should be N/2, is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

You're saying that they wanted you to recreate/reinvent the ["diehard" battery of tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) that it took Marsaglia many years to develop? I'd call them on unreasonable expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever distribution the random floats are suppposed to have, say uniform distribution over the interval [0,1], you can use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test to test to see if a sample does not follow the desired distribution. This can have advantages over chi-squared test if you have many possible values (because if you have more possible values than samples, then you have to define buckets for the chi-squared test, which makes the test less powerful compared to general distribution checking like Kolmogorov-Smirnov)

Comment: As with amit's answer, this tests for uniformity but not for randomness.

Comment: @pjs Right but the current set of randomness tests is in no way "complete", i.e. they don't prove that a sequence has no patterns, and the existing tests are complex and took years to develop like you pointed out. I think checking for uniformity, maybe with a little baby test for randomness like checking that there are no unusual increasing/decreasing subsequences should be enough for a phone interview.

Comment: If you want randomness, uniformity is the least interesting aspect of it - I can convert any continuous distribution to a uniform by mapping it through its Cumulative Distribution Function. I agree that tests such as distribution of the length for increasing/decreasing runs, runs above/below the mean, uniformity of k-tuples, birthday duplicates, etc., will help with ruling out non-random sequences.  A test for uniformity won't, there are lots of sequences that are random but not uniform.