# Easier way to convert a 64 bit float to a bit list

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to convert a float to a bit list.

Here is my idea:

1. read all bits info from a `float` to an `Int64`
2. `mod 2` 64 times and each time store the `0` or `1` to a list
3. Deal with the negative case (applying 2's complement plus one)

The code is like this:

```
let convert_non_neg_64 n =
  let rec collect acc i j =
    if Int64.compare j (Int64.of_int 64) <> -1 then acc
    else collect ((Int64.rem i (Int64.of_int 2) |> Int64.to_int)::acc) (Int64.div i (Int64.of_int 2)) (Int64.succ j)
  in 
  collect [] n Int64.zero

let negatify l =
  let rl = List.rev_map (fun x -> if x = 0 then 1 else 0) l in
  let rec plus1 extra acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | hd::tl when extra = 0 -> plus1 0 (hd::acc) tl
    | hd::tl -> if hd = 0 then plus1 0 (1::acc) tl else plus1 1 (0::acc) tl
  in 
  plus1 1 [] rl

let convert64 n =
  let nnl = convert_non_neg_64 (Int64.abs n) in 
  if Int64.compare n Int64.zero <> -1 then nnl
  else negatify nnl

let bits_of_float fn = Int64.bits_of_float fn |> convert64
```

---

I think the code is fine.

My question is **is there an easier way**?

Also, all those `Int64` operations are really ugly, any good way to simplify it?

Comment: `Int64` is not really the kind of module intended to be opened, but you can always write `Int64.(…)` around the expressions that need it most.

Comment: In the place where you wrote `Int64.compare n Int64.zero <> -1` you meant `Int64.compare n Int64.zero >= 0` (which you can write `Int64.(compare n zero) >= 0`). The `compare` functions should not be assumed to return -1 or 1.

Comment: The simplest expression for `Int64.compare j (Int64.of_int 64) <> -1` is `j >= 64L`.

Comment: I don't see why you need to treat negatives specially. If you use bit operations you don't need to care about numeric values. Int64.logand can check the low bit (or any bit).

Comment: @JeffreyScofield what do you mean? I think the bit representation of negative is different?

Comment: Int64.bits_of_float lets you see the bits of a floating value. Every bit is just a bit. There's no need to think of the whole thing as a positive or negative 64-bit integer. If you want something other than a faithful copy of the bits, then that's different.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield It seems negative float doesn't use 2's complement, not like negative int. Then how should I convert a float to bits? Do I need to read all those bits to an Int64 first?

Comment: @JeffreyScofield what do you mean by faithful copy of bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
let bitlist_of_float f =
    let rec blist b i64 =
        if b >= 64 then
            []
        else
            let bit =
                Int64.(if logand i64 (shift_left 1L b) = 0L then 0 else 1)
            in
            bit :: blist (b + 1) i64
    in  
    blist 0 (Int64.bits_of_float f)
```

The head of the list is the least significant bit (which I believe is the right way to do things). I have not verified the answers, so there could be an error or two.

**Update**

I believe this code will give you the bits of your floating value. That's all I mean by "faithful copy." If you wanted to modify the bits somehow, then you'd need to work on them a little more. I'm not sure what you have in mind to do with them.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916519/test-the-randomness-of-a-black-box-that-outputs-random-64-bit-floats/22917716?noredirect=1#22917716